# linux one liner, show name of files matching a pattern

Tags: linux, grep, cat

Let us say I have a list of files with extension .txt.

And I'd like to know what is the name of the files that match a regex pattern, how would I do that in linux.

Right now I am doing:

```
cat *.txt | grep -f list.txt
```

where list.txt contains a list of regex patterns.

This command only shows me that the pattern was matched but I cannot see the name of the file that matched it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join both conditions into something like this:

```
grep -f list.txt *.txt
```

Comment: No problem! It happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you only need names, so you need `-l` argument.

```
grep -l -f list.txt *.txt
```